# How to plot directed network connectivity in a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, networking, connectivity

I'm new to R studio and I need to plot a directed network. I have a node and edge .csv files
[image: First rows of the node file]

[image: First rows of the edge file]

So far I've just been able to plot in the map the points receiving particles

[image: West Coast of Scotland]

I'm facing several issues here. The first one is that not all the points receiving particles are properly observed in the map because of the color code and dimension of the circles.

The second issue is that I also need to plot the target points, but I only manage to plot those receiving particles.

And I need to connect source points with target points (connected by lines more or less thickness depending on the particles sended by the source point).

This is my code:

```
require(rgdal)
require(ggplot2)
fn <- file.path(tempdir(), "GBR_adm_gdb.zip", fsep = "\\")
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/GBR_adm_shp.zip", fn)
utils::unzip(fn, exdir = tempdir())
shp <- readOGR(dsn = file.path(tempdir(), "GBR_adm1.shp"), stringsAsFactors = F)

nodes <- read.csv("C:/Users/.../NODES.csv" , header=TRUE)
head(nodes)

edges <- read.csv("C:/Users/.../edges.csv" , header=TRUE)
head(edges)

map <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = shp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_point (data = nodes,
              aes(x = as.numeric(Longitude),
                  y = as.numeric(Latitude), size = ParticlesReceived, color =ParticlesReceived), alpha = .9) +
  geom_line() +

  scale_size_area(max_size =8) +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3, 
              xlim = c(-8,-4.5), 
              ylim = c(55.3, 59))
  
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
nodes <- structure(list(ID = c("T1", "T2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", 
"A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", 
"A17_P", "A18", "A19", "A20", "A21", "A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", 
"A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A30", "T3", "T7", "T4", "T5", "T6", 
"T8", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", 
"A39", "A40", "A41", "A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", 
"A48", "A49", "A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55", "A56", 
"A57", "A58", "A59", "A60", "A61", "A62", "A63_B", "", "", ""
), Name = c("Eil", "Linnhe", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", 
"S9", "S10", "S11", "S12", "S13", "S14", "S15", "S16", "S17_P", 
"S18", "S19", "S20", "S21", "S22", "S23", "S24", "S25", "S26", 
"S27", "S28", "S29", "S30", "Sunart", "Spelve", "Roag", "Badcall", 
"Laxford", "Cairidih", "S31", "S32", "S33", "S34", "S35", "S36", 
"S37", "S38", "S39", "S40", "S41", "S42", "S43", "S44", "S45", 
"S46", "S47", "S48", "S49", "S50", "S51", "S52", "S53", "S54", 
"S55", "S56", "S57", "S58", "S59", "S60", "S61", "S62", "S63_B", 
"", "", ""), Longitude = c(-5.172, -5.171, -5.973, -5.279, -5.371, 
-6.557, -5.79, -6.612, -7.511, -7.203, -7.137, -7.35, -5.909, 
-6.016, -6.028, -6.119, -6.147, -5.266, -6.215, -5.882, -5.743, 
-5.845, -5.467, -7.639, -7.596, -7.063, -7.507, -7.375, -7.436, 
-6.817, -5.728755, -5.965663, -6.768254, -5.151579, -5.082169, 
-5.931472, -6.34, -6.892, -5.946, -6.255, -6.324, -5.515, -6.458, 
-6.284, -6.427, -6.399, -5.631, -6.768, -6.04, -6.274, -5.946, 
-6.435, -7.35, -5.968, -6.573, -6.762, -6.29, -7.13, -7, -7.764, 
-6.935, -6.966, -5.663, -6.964, -7.315, -5.973, -6.685, -6.559, 
-7.391053, NA, NA, NA), Latitude = c(56.85, 56.77, 56.56, 56.69, 
56.64, 57.25, 57.3, 57.3, 56.85, 57.23, 57.33, 56.95, 57.02, 
56.97, 56.82, 57.1, 57.42, 58.24, 57.65, 57.44, 57.6, 57.44, 
57.39, 56.75, 56.76, 57.96, 57.09, 57.7, 57.2, 58.32, 56.39908, 
56.668643, 58.220343, 58.316558, 58.394389, 57.277806, 56.24, 
56.44, 56.05, 56.54, 56.55, 56.55, 56.61, 56.2, 56.18, 56.27, 
56.47, 56.5, 55.98, 56.24, 56.05, 56.36, 56.95, 56.9, 57.03, 
57.39, 57.13, 56.37, 56.17, 56.38, 55.93, 55.78, 56.05, 56.42, 
56.53, 56.56, 56.44, 56.58, 56.997312, NA, NA, NA), ParticlesReceived = c(625L, 
235L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
326L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4951L, 
829L, 9291L, 774L, 454L, 145L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2768L, NA, NA, NA), Type = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 72L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
edges <- structure(list(Source = c("T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T1", "A3", 
"A4", "A5", "T2", "T1", "A6", "A7", "A17_P", "A18", "A8", "A20", 
"A19", "A8", "A18", "A20", "A6", "A21", "A7", "A22", "A25", "A9", 
"A10", "A26", "A27", "A11", "A12", "A24", "A28", "A29", "A30", 
"A15", "A13", "A14", "A16", "A23", "T3", "T7", "T4", "T8", "T6", 
"A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", "A39", 
"A40", "A41", "A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48", 
"A49", "A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55", "A56", "A57", 
"A58", "A59", "A60", "A61", "A62"), Target = c("T1", "T2", "T2", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T7", "T7", "T7", "T7", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", 
"T5", "T5", "T5", "T6", "T6", "T6", "T6", "T6", "T6", "T6", "T4", 
"T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T8", 
"T8", "T8", "T8", "T8", "T3", "T7", "T4", "T5", "T6", "A63_B", 
"A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", 
"A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", 
"A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", 
"A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A63_B", "A17_P", "A17_P", 
"A17_P", "A17_P", "A17_P"), particles = c(625L, 127L, 108L, 352L, 
234L, 112L, 83L, 61L, 35L, 22L, 202L, 186L, 154L, 77L, 75L, 41L, 
32L, 160L, 47L, 46L, 40L, 40L, 23L, 19L, 504L, 336L, 299L, 294L, 
275L, 168L, 168L, 168L, 168L, 152L, 136L, 52L, 43L, 20L, 19L, 
11L, 4365L, 628L, 6623L, 7L, 79L, 143L, 67L, 37L, 29L, 300L, 
87L, 142L, 194L, 38L, 56L, 108L, 33L, 25L, 148L, 101L, 51L, 211L, 
152L, 336L, 39L, 24L, 109L, 84L, 90L, 36L, 35L, 93L, 33L, 67L, 
134L, 60L, 32L)), row.names = c(NA, 77L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share (some of) the data you are using? use `dput(head(nodes, 100))` and `dput(head(edges, 100))`.

Comment: Hi, I just put it at the end of the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw edges between node you're better off transforming your data to a graph.

```r
require(tidygraph)
particles_graph <- tbl_graph(nodes, edges, node_key= "ID")
```

Once you have it in a graph format, you can use the [ggraph package](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph).

We first have to create a manual layout with the coordinate system:

```r
particle_coord_layout <- create_layout(graph = particles_graph,
              layout = "manual", 
              x = nodes$Longitude,
              y = nodes$Latitude)
```

And then we can create a crude graph:

```r
ggraph(particle_coord_layout) +
  geom_polygon(data = shp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(width=particles), alpha = .5) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = ParticlesReceived)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3, 
              xlim = c(-7.6,-4.8), 
              ylim = c(55.8, 58.6)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
#> Regions defined for each Polygons
```

[image]

Exploring the `ggraph` package we can improve the results:

```r
ggraph(particle_coord_layout) +
  geom_polygon(data = shp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "grey85") +
  geom_edge_diagonal(aes(width=particles, alpha=after_stat(index), color=particles)) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label=Name, size = ParticlesReceived), alpha=.8) +
  scale_edge_width_continuous(range=c(1,3)) +
  scale_edge_color_gradientn(colors = scales::brewer_pal("seq", direction = 1)(5)[3:5]) +
  scale_edge_alpha(range=c(0,1)) +
  scale_size(range=c(2,6)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3, 
              xlim = c(-7.6,-4.8), 
              ylim = c(55.8, 58.6)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
#> Regions defined for each Polygons
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: THank you very much for this. This is exactly what I needed it. Just a question, do you know why your figure has more resolution than the one I obtained? And do you know if it could be possible to add arrows in the lines to indicate the direction (from source to target)?

Comment: No idea about resolution, sry, it's mostly determined on how you saved the graph (hint: `ggsave`). About the arrow: `geom_edge_diagonal` does have an `arrow` argument, that accepts an `arrow()` object. Unfortunately this [does not play well](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/143) with `after_stat(index)` used for the alpha. You can either have the `alpha` or the `arrow`. See `?geom_edge_diagonal` for details.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll play around with it. One last question about this. The connections shown in the map are made in the water, they are particles swiming in the water. Do you know if it's possible to avoid the lines being in the land?